# Icon stacking on the LXDE panel (Aero style)

Tags: lubuntu, icons, lxde

One of the things I enjoy about Unity  is the icon stacking.  That is, having a shortcut icon on the launcher and when opening that application, the icons group together, rather than having multiple icons on the launcher.

My current setup is a set of applications and a launcher widget. How to achieve the "stacking" effect?

[Here is a screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/pebnzgc05/) of my desktop with 4 open windows (Lubuntu Software Center, Chrome x2 and Terminal)

**Note:**

My application shortcuts are (from top down) LXDE Menu, Thunar, Chrome, Mousepad, System Monitor and Lubuntu Software Center.
After LSC begins my launcher widget showing LSC, Chrome and Terminal open.
The Chrome instance is expanded to indicate there are 2 open instances.

**What I want to do is as follows:**

The open applications should not show in an open window list but instead "stack" inside the original icon similar to [this screenshot's](http://thevarguy.com/site-files/thevarguy.com/files/archive/thevarguy.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/screenshot47.png) Firefox, gedit, mousepad and Terminal instances.  Or [like in Windows 7](http://i44.tinypic.com/rbmu8i.png).  These are both Launchers AND indicators of open instances.

Sorry for the long post but I hope the verbosity makes my intent more clear.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But... You want to have the visuals of Ubuntu on Lubuntu?

Comment: no, sorry.  Let me try again.  on the lxde panel, i want to show one icon representing both the launcher and the current open windows of that application (stacked).  As it stands now, I have one icon for the launcher and (if the app is open) one for the open windows (grouped).  Both Unity and Windows 7 do this.

Comment: Just post the picture link in the comments without the HTTP and I'll figure it out! ;-)

Comment: Any ideas on this?

Comment: I understand clearly now, but I wouldn't know where to start to do this.  Upvoted your question to attract more knowledgeable people then me!

Comment: Any feedback on a better name to call the functionality I am referring to?  Does this have a formal name?

Comment: Edited your question for clarity and added a few more tags to attract more competent people then me...  I *really can't do more then this...*  :-(